# How to use DataAnnotations to check a property only matches an array of string

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have an attribute:

```
[MaxLength(3)]
public string State { get; set; }
```

on the property named `State` and I only want it to match given 5 Australian states: 
`{ "VIC", "NSW", "QLD", "SA", "TAS", "WA" }`. How can I use DataAnnotations for this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [RegularExpressionAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

```
[RegularExpression("VIC|NSW|QLD|TAS|WA|SA")]
[MaxLength(3)]
public string State { get; set; }
```

which should only allow VIC, NSW, QLD, TAS, WA, or SA

Comment: @Krishna Muppalla great solution, this was what I was working on.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an attribute inheriting from `ValidationAttribute` for this.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true)]
public class StringRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{       
    public string[] AllowableValues { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string actualValue = value as string;

        if (AllowableValues?.Contains(actualValue) == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[StringRange(AllowableValues = new string[] { "VIC", "NSW", "QLD", "SA", "TAS", "WA"})]
public string State{ get; set; }
```

Here we're using Linq's `Contains` method on the array.

If you require a case-insensitive option then as Codexer points out you could use:

```
if (AllowableValues?.Contains(actualValue?.ToUpper()) == true)
```

Comment: `if (AllowableValues?.Contains(actualValue) == true)` wouldn't this allow per say `vic` instead of `VIC`? Maybe `if (AllowableValues?.Contains(actualValue.ToUpper()) == true)`

Comment: No, I don't believe so. Contains is case sensitive afaik.

Comment: If user wants specific value (case sensitive), contains will not work as it's not case sensitive, maybe the OP can chime in on  this?

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. Yes sorry, you're right. Depends what OP wants @Çöđěxěŕ.  I thought you were saying it would allow `vic` and `VIC`.  This answer is case sensitive.

Comment: no problem, just didn't know if user want's specific sensitivity, they didn't mention this, my assumptions are just off what the OP posted. Anyways, a great alternative than the selected answer.